# Resizing a rotated container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vector;
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TestComp(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestComp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestCompState createState() => _TestCompState();
}

class _TestCompState extends State<TestComp> {
  double _y = 0;
  double _x = 0;

  double _height = 200;
  double _width = 300;

  int angle = -136;

  vector.Vector4 testRotation(var dx, var dy) {
    vector.Matrix4 matrix = vector.Matrix4.identity();
    matrix..rotateZ(math.pi / 180 * angle);
    return matrix * vector.Vector4(dx, dy, 0, 0);
  }

  double get _aspectRatio {
    return _height / _width;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: _y,
          left: _x,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: math.pi / 180 * angle, //-136,
            child: Container(
              height: _height,
              width: _width,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Stack(
                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        var newdx =
                            testRotation(details.delta.dx, details.delta.dy)[0];
                        var newdy =
                            testRotation(details.delta.dx, details.delta.dy)[1];
                        setState(() {
                          _y += newdy;
                          _x += newdx;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Image.network(
                        "https://via.placeholder.com/300x200",
                        height: _height,
                        width: _width,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                        var position = testRotation(
                          details.delta.dx,
                          details.delta.dy,
                        );
                        // print(position);
                        var dx = position[0];
                        var dy = position[1];

                        var newWidth = _width - dx;
                        var newHeight = newWidth * _aspectRatio;
                        setState(() {
                          _y = _y + (_height - newHeight);
                          _x = _x + dx;
                          _width = newWidth;
                          _height = newHeight;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

There's a handle in top left of image which will be used to resize. I expect the rotation to be like:

[image]

But it doesn't work that way. The resize is messed up. Please help me in this.

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your answer but that looks complicated as hell lol. I will look into it.

Comment: @pskink I mean your code looks complicated to me. Only me not in general.

Comment: @pskink Where is the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this `FooResizer` widget - you could add 4 additional corner sizers in the same way:

```
final SIZE = 64.0;
final sizerSize = Size.square(SIZE);

final sizers = [
  Sizer(Alignment.centerLeft, EdgeInsets.only(left: 1), Offset(1, 0)),
  Sizer(Alignment.topCenter, EdgeInsets.only(top: 1), Offset(0, 1)),
  Sizer(Alignment.centerRight, EdgeInsets.only(right: 1), Offset(-1, 0)),
  Sizer(Alignment.bottomCenter, EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1), Offset(0, -1)),
];

class Sizer {
  final Alignment alignment;
  final EdgeInsets insets;
  final Offset mask;
  Sizer(this.alignment, this.insets, this.mask);
}

class FooResizer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooResizerState createState() => _FooResizerState();
}

class _FooResizerState extends State<FooResizer> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  ValueNotifier<Rect> rect;
  ValueNotifier<int> serial = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  Sizer currentSizer;
  Rect savedRect;
  Offset savedOffset;
  AnimationController controller;
  GlobalKey stackKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller ??= AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        _init(constraints.biggest);
        return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: Listenable.merge([rect, serial, controller]),
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Transform.rotate(
              angle: math.pi / 8,
              child: Stack(
                key: stackKey,
                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                children: [
                  Positioned.fromRect(
                    rect: rect.value,
                    child: Material(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: FlutterLogo(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ...sizers.map(_sizerBuilder),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _sizerBuilder(Sizer sizer) {
    var isCurrent = currentSizer == sizer;
    var finalRect = sizer.alignment.inscribe(sizerSize, rect.value).shift(sizer.mask * SIZE * -0.33);
    var centerRect = Alignment.center.inscribe(sizerSize, rect.value);
    var interpolated = Rect.lerp(finalRect, centerRect, isCurrent? 0 : controller.value);
    return Positioned.fromRect(
      rect: interpolated,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: (details) => _panStart(sizer, details),
        onPanUpdate: _panUpdate,
        onPanEnd: _panEnd,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: isCurrent? 1 : 1 - controller.value,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: isCurrent? Duration(milliseconds: 500) : Duration.zero,
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: isCurrent? RoundedRectangleBorder() : CircleBorder(),
              color: isCurrent? Colors.orange[800] : Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _panStart(Sizer sizer, DragStartDetails details) {
    // timeDilation = 10;
    currentSizer = sizer;
    savedRect = rect.value;
    savedOffset = _invertedOffset(details.globalPosition);
    serial.value++;
    controller.forward();
  }

  _panUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    assert(currentSizer != null);
    var delta = savedOffset - _invertedOffset(details.globalPosition);
    var insets = EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
      currentSizer.insets.left * delta.dx * currentSizer.mask.dx,
      currentSizer.insets.top * delta.dy * currentSizer.mask.dy,
      currentSizer.insets.right * delta.dx * currentSizer.mask.dx,
      currentSizer.insets.bottom * delta.dy * currentSizer.mask.dy,
    );
    rect.value = insets.inflateRect(savedRect);
  }

  _panEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    assert(currentSizer != null);
    currentSizer = null;
    serial.value++;
    controller.reverse();
  }

  Offset _invertedOffset(Offset offset) {
    RenderBox rb = stackKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    return rb.globalToLocal(offset);
  }

  void _init(Size size) {
    var r = Offset.zero & size;
    rect = ValueNotifier(r.deflate(100));
  }
}
```

and the result would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thanks, But I need a use case where we can add items dynamically and position, scale, and rotate them (like image editor). Positioning and scaling work fine in this method. But how to implement rotation? I tried to use Transform.rotate but it rotate the widget only , not the sizers.

Comment: @AbhijithK it is prepared for rotation: now it is fixed `angle: math.pi / 8,` - you need to change it with some `angle: rotationAngle`

Comment: But how will we configure it for multiple objects that are dynamically inserted. Each dynamically inserted object should be able to scale rotate and resize. For this the Transform.rotate should be in a stack. Right ?

Comment: @AbhijithK  in `Stack` or `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: can you solve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843059/position-resize-and-rotate-flutter-widget-dynamically-with-gesture