# Flutter Transform | origin vs alignment

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to know the difference between the origin and alignment property of the Transform widget. What will happen if we set both origin and alignment? From docs, what I understood is both and setting the origin.

**origin**

The origin of the coordinate system (relative to the upper left corner of this render object) in which to apply the matrix.

**Alignment**

The alignment of the origin, relative to the size of the box.
This is equivalent to setting an origin based on the size of the box.
If it is specified at the same time as the [origin], both are applied.

Comment: alignment is useful if you want to a apply your transform against for example center of your widget, while origin is useful if you know exact coordinates

Comment: what I exactly need is, I am creating a widget resize functionality with transform widget. So there are 4 anchor points on mid of each edge. If I click and drag on the top anchor point, it should scale with respect to the bottom anchor point. So I dynamically change the origin of the transform widget based on the anchor point user click. Even though the widget scales, its size value doesn't increase.

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427558/2252830?

Comment: @pskink exactly. let me try that.

Answer (score 1):

`Origin` is used to fix X and Y positions.

```dart
Center(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: Transform(
      origin: Offset(20,40) ,
      //alignment: Alignment.center,
      transform: Matrix4.skewY(0.3)..rotateZ(24 / 12.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        color: const Color(0xFFE8581C),
        child: const Text('hello'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

whereas `Alignment` shows the specific position like `center`, `left`,`centerRight`, etc.