# Position Resize and Rotate Flutter Widget dynamically with gesture

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am developing an image editor in flutter. For that, I need to add a feature of adding images and text dynamically to the screen. Each of them should be able to independently scale, position, and rotate. There should be an anchor point like in word or in photoshop to indicate the active image and to scale and rotate them(sample in the image). The image should be positioned with drag and drop.

[image]

The widget should be able to scale in x, in y, and in both xy.

**Things I have tried**

**1.matrix_gesture_detector**
I think this package doesn't have the option to scale only in x  or only in y. It uniformly scales the widget in x and y. Also making the active image with something like in the image is difficult. If we wrap the active image in a custom widget like in the image, the widget also scales with the image. For eg if the border thickness is 1 px when scaled the thickness also scales making it wired.

**2. Using Transform Widget.**
When the transform widget is used the above-mentioned problem of the widget indication the active image around the image also scales with the widget. Also in transform when scaling I have to adjust the alignment or the origin dynamically with respect to the scaling chosen. For eg, if I want to scale in the top direction only, I have to set the anchor point to the bottomCenter.But here the anchor points are set with respect to the initial size of the widget. So when changing the anchor point to scale in a different direction, the widget jumps to a corresponding alignment position with respect to the original size of the widget.

**3. Using Positioned.fromRect**
I have tried this solution from StackOverflow
[Resizing a rotated container in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410463/resizing-a-rotated-container-in-flutter/64427558?noredirect=1#comment119904046_64427558), but here the problem is the solution is only for one widget. So I wrapped that in a stack. But when rotated, it rotates the full stack. The stack takes the height and width of the canvas. So the alignment of the anchor point of the transform widget is with respect to that and not with respect to the image.

NB: I am using Getx for state managemanet. If you can provide the solution in getx, that is preferred.

Comment: I think you want to have a full-screen Stack where each child is wrapped in that "resize a rotated container" solution. When a widget is selected, you might bring it to the top of the stack, remembering where it belongs when done.

Comment: @JacobPhillips ya. I have tried that. As mentioned in the question, there are problems in one way or other. So I need a detailed explanation.

Comment: My suggestion works around the issue of rotating the whole stack

Comment: @JacobPhillips.  Rotating the whole stack sets the rotating anchor point with respect to the stack. Right? But we need to set the anchor point for rotation with respect to the Widget item only. Isnt it?

Comment: I'm saying you should put the rotating widget inside the stack, perhaps the rotating widget also has a stack, but that would not be a problem.

Comment: I have already tried, I think. But How to show the active layer then /

Comment: Do you want like this?https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/72498175/121304695-4d692080-c91a-11eb-8959-140c79b36ac4.mp4

Comment: @SanketVekariya I have tried something like this(link in the 3rd point in the question). But this is only for one widget. Right? also, it doesn't show the rotation. I need multiple widgets to be rotated resized and positioned.

Comment: If you are sure the link I have shared here is the same you want, I can put my efforts further to achieve rotation too.

Comment: @SanketVekariya ya fine. But the scaling functionality in the sample is not functioning exactly as I expected. In the sample when you scale by clicking the bottom green point, It scales with respect to the center of the image(that is, its scale on both sides, top, and bottom). I only need the side we drag to be scaled. (something like in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410463/resizing-a-rotated-container-in-flutter/64427558?noredirect=1#comment119904046_64427558).

Comment: @SanketVekariya. I have tried the solution in the above link I have given in the previous comment and it works perfectly fine. But the problem with that is mentioned in the question in point 3.Using Positioned.fromRect. If you can solve that,it will do

Comment: you can simply manipulate insets in _panUpdate method to achieve your idea.

Comment: @SanketVekariya Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233561/discussion-between-abhijith-k-and-sanket-vekariya).

Comment: @AbhijithK any updates? I'm just thinking maybe we should inherit SingleChildRenderObjectWidget and RenderBox to achieve this

Comment: @SajadAbdollahi not yet. Can you explain in detail

Comment: @AbhijithK for creating a custom widget from scratch, we need to extend SingleChildRenderObjectWidget and then provide a class named RenderCustomFrame extending RenderShiftedBox to it, then we create the sizing handlers inside the RenderCustomFrame and put our gesture recognizers in that, we paint the widgets using 4 points of corners in RenderCustomFrame and when resizing or rotating the widget we just change the position of those 4 points and reCreate the widget,   I'm very very new to this so maybe I'm wrong, I recommend you to watch videos of creativecreatorormaybenot in youtube.

Comment: @SajadAbdollahi I have already watched that video on render object. Let me try the way you suggested. But the photobooth by flutter implements somewhat what i need without the render object. They use the basic material widgets.

Comment: @AbhijithK Photobooth is opensource so can't you just copy their code I mean whats the problem here

Comment: @SajadAbdollahi It's not exactly what I need, I am working on it

Comment: any solution ??

Answer (score 1):

You can warp a Stack->Positioned->Transform.rotate->Your Widget.
Also refer the source code of photobooth.

Comment: not that simple